# How to update code on multiple release build by code-push immediately

Tags: react-native, code-push

I have a question -

How to release an update of APK (Lets Say X) so that X APK running on any device, are updated immediately ?

Answer (score 0):

With expo's codepush, the published bundle is deployed really fast. Your users must reboot / kill the app in order to get the last version of the code.

With expo, there's tools to check is there's a new bundle available and then, reboot the app yourself.

My advice would be to not push new features in your app if you planning to release on iOS since apple terms says you shouldn't do it (check apple store rules). On android there's no problem.

One last thing, you can't push native code. So if you install a new plugin which requires `react-native link <plugin-name>` the app might crash in production.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make release which should be installed immediately(even if your current code-push setting isn't `installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE`) you should use mandatory update feature. For this just use `-m` option for release command. This release will be installed immediately for your app. For more info check: https://github.com/Microsoft/code-push/blob/master/cli/README.md#mandatory-parameter